# MySQL - How to use IF condition to decide which columns to INSERT

Tags: mysql, list, if-statement, insert, field

I am writing a stored procedure to import data from one database to another one with a completely different table structure. So I'm looking for a method to help me decide for example, if the source column is treatment_type then insert record into target's text_column (with data type varchar) but if the source column is date_enrolled then insert into target's date_column (with data type datetime). Here is a sample code.

if source column = treatment_type

```
INSERT INTO target_table
        (target_id, text_column)
```

if source column = date_enrolled

```
INSERT INTO target_table
        (target_id, date_column)
```

Basically I am iterating through this cursor below (which gives me all the columns from the source, over 100 columns at least)

```
DECLARE col_names CURSOR FOR SELECT column_name
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
        WHERE table_schema = 'source_db' and table_name = 'source_table';
```

and I would like to create one single insert statement for each column, deciding each time the target column to insert to. Something similar to this.

```
FETCH col_names INTO col_name;

IF col_name = 'date_enrolled' THEN
    SET @target_column= 'date_column';
ELSE
    SET @target_column= 'text_column';
END IF;

INSERT INTO taget_table
    (target_id,  @target_column)
VALUES (
    if(col_name='tretment_type', 1, if(col_name='date_enrolled', 2, null)), 
    if(col_name='tretment_type', 'malaria', if(col_name='date_enrolled', '2020-06-03', null))
)
```

I will appreciate all ideas. Thank you!

Comment: `... SET column_name = CASE WHEN col_name = 'column_marker' THEN 'inserted data' ELSE column_name END ...` - i.e. when marker points to this column then it is assigned to new value else old value is re-assigned back (really data won't be updated for this column). Apply this for both columns.

Comment: I am having a hard time visualising what you are trying to do, if you could provide sample data based on 6 columns together with expected result (as text) that might help.

Comment: If I'm getting your idea, you may accomplish what you are looking for by using a prepare statement inside the loop raising the following two issues: You may need to set up 100 conditional variables(one per column) to set up the prepare statement and; I can not see where you data comes from other than hard coding them , and again either mapping (hard coding) one set of data per column or using default values for each one.I would look into making a conventional Insert statement.

Comment: Thanks @Erick prepared statement looks promising. Let me try it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this using a Prepared statement to construct the query. But first, I had to introduce a second cursor (`col_types`) to help me decide the column to insert to (`target_column`). So now the code sample that worked looks like this:

```
DECLARE col_names CURSOR FOR SELECT column_name
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE table_schema = 'source_db' and table_name = 'source_table';

DECLARE col_types CURSOR FOR SELECT if(column_name = 'date_enrollment', 'date_column', 'text_column') as 'column_name'
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE table_schema = 'source_db' and table_name = 'source_table';

SELECT FOUND_ROWS() into num_rows;

OPEN col_names;
OPEN col_types;
SET i = 1;
the_loop: LOOP
    IF i > num_rows THEN
        CLOSE col_names;
        CLOSE col_types;
        LEAVE the_loop;
    END IF;

    FETCH col_names INTO col_name;
    FETCH col_types INTO target_column;

    -- creates target data for each source record
    SET @qrySQL= CONCAT("INSERT INTO taget_table
    (target_id,  ", target_column ,")
    VALUES (",
        if(col_name='tretment_type', 1, if(col_name='date_enrolled', 2, null)), 
        if(col_name='tretment_type', 'malaria', if(col_name='date_enrolled', '2020-06-03', 
        null))
    ,"
    );");

   PREPARE qryStmt FROM @qrySQL;

   EXECUTE qryStmt ;

   DEALLOCATE PREPARE qryStmt;

    SET i = i + 1;  
END LOOP the_loop;
```

Thanks guys!